# How can I fix Flutter_localizations error on the vscode? - Target of URI doesn't exist

Tags: flutter, flutter-localizations

I'm trying to use flutter_localizations and I followed this [guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization)

When I save pubspec.yaml on vscode then pub get is ran.

After that vscode can't find app_localizations.dart file.

But this error messages will disappear when I reopen vscode.

Is there anyone with such a problem like me?

Thanks.

[image: AppLocalizations Error]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this command and Open command palette - `command + shift + p` on the vscode.

Type `Dart: Restart Analysis Server` and select it.

This error will be gone.

Answer (score 2):

Usually running

```
flutter gen-l10n
```

should be enough, however sometimes I'va found myself using

```
flutter clean && flutter pub get dependencies && flutter packages get
```

To clean cache, and get the dependencies(which also generate the l10n). 95% of the time the first command should suffice